# Regex: strip out if not "OBX"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have data like this:

```
MSH|1|data1|data2|data3
PID|1|data5|data6|data7
PVI|1|data2|data2|data2
OBX|1|data0|data4|data9
OBX|2|data8|data8|data9
OBX|3|data1|data1|data1
```

I am trying regex to strip out any lines that don't start with OBX. Here's what I have so far:

```
message = message.replace(/^(?!OBX).+/g, '');
```

Even though I have `/g` it only triggered on the first. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: A vote to close? Is regex not appropriate here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using anchor `^` in your regex, you will need to use `m` flag (MULTILINE):

```
message = message.replace(/^(?!OBX).+/gm, '');
```

Without `m` modifier your regex will match `^` only at the start of very first line instead of matching before every line.

[RegEx Demo](http://%5E(?!OBX).%20/gm)